# How to remove separator line from listview on IOS?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm facing issue in removing separator line after each list item and not able to change the separator line color.

I have tried separatorColor="transparent" property in Listview tag and in CSS but both of them are not working. 
I have tried SeparatorVisibility="None" property also, but no luck.

I have tried [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3599) solution provided by GitHub, but it is not working.

Here is the code :

```
<GridLayout row="1" class="shop-list-container">
    <ListView [items]="rewardsPageData?.shops" class="list-group"  height="{{rewardsPageData?.shops?.length * 75}}" separatorColor="transparent">
        <ng-template let-shop="item">
            <GridLayout class="shop-item list-group-item" columns="2*, 6*, 2*" rows="*, auto" (tap)="goToShopDetails(shop.id)">
                <Image src="{{shop.logoImageUrl}}" class="thumb img-circle" col="0" row="0" rowSpan="2" horizontalAlignment="left"></Image>
                <Label class="shop-name" [text]="shop.title" row="0" col="1"></Label>
                <Label class="shop-type" text="{{shop?.category}}" row="1" col="1"></Label>
                <Label text="See location" class="see-location-text" textWrap="true" col="2" row="0" rowSpan="2" horizontalAlignment="right"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: On my side the inline property works just fine https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WIdwdA&v=2

Answer (score 6):

I created an [isolated example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=RmqTjG&v=2) with setting separator-color to transparent in CSS and works just fine for me in iOS. Notice the ListView rule in app.css.

It works equally well if you remove the CSS rule and set `separatorColor="transparent"` to the ListView object in home.component.html.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried both ways but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Add this following line in your `_app-common.scss` file

```
  ListView { separator-color: transparent; }
```

Also, when creating a ListView, use `class = "list-group"`